# Android - Query audio files only on specific folder (exclude sub folders)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-music-player

I'm trying to query the list of audio files from external content URI on specific folder. But all the audios on sub folders are also includes.

How to get only audios on specific folder and exclude subfolder.

This is what i tried to do .

```
 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
            uri, projection,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? " , new String[]{"%/storage/emulated/0/Music/Tamil/%"} , null);
```

Please let me know if the query is wrong

I tried multiple answers on StackOverflow , but none worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String folder = "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Tamil";
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " NOT LIKE ? ";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
        "%" + folder + "%",
        "%" + folder + "/%/%"
};
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

Comment: You sir, made my day today

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
// The folder needs to end with the % wildcard or stuff doesn't work properly.
String folder = "/mnt/sdcard/Music/Some Folder/";
folder = folder + "%";
String where = Artists._ID + " IN (SELECT " + Media.ARTIST_ID + " FROM audio WHERE " +
    Media.DATA + " LIKE ?)";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{folder};
audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Artist.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    cols, where, whereArgs, AudioColumns.ARTIST + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

Comment: I tried this answer from another question , but it doesn't work. I picks all the audio including the sub folders